# Expectation of random unit vectors

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, inner-products

I am looking into the problem where $X$ is a random variable defined on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with $X\sim N(0, I_d)$ and I want to find,
$$E\left\{\frac{\langle X-u_1, X-u_2\rangle}{\|X-u_1\|\|X-u_2\|}\right\},$$

interms of $u_1$ and $u_2$, where $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the usual inner product and norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$ respectively and $u_1,u_2\in\mathbb{R}^d$ are fixed points.

I do not know whether there is any existing similar problem that has been discussed in this platform or anywhere else; I could not find any. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Intuitively, this should be $(u_1,u_2)$ because each unit vector is matched by one in the opposite direction and each is equally likely to occur.

Comment: I would be quite surprised if this is tractable.

Comment: Just as observation, if $u_1=u_2$ you get 1 surely.  If $u_1=-u_2$, you get 0 surely.  It's a inner product of unit vectors, so the answer is the expected value of $\cos \theta$, with the angle being between the 2 unit vectors.

Comment: @JohnDouma can you please elaborate a little more. Also, did you meant $\langle u_1,u_2\rangle/\|u_1\|\|u_2\|$?

Comment: @Paul You are absolutely right. It is $E\{\cos(\theta)\}$, $\theta$ being the angle between the unit vectors. Thus the existence of this expectation is always guaranteed. Also Cauchy-Schwartz inequality guarantees the existence of this integral.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about a closed form, but you can turn the $d$ dimensional integral into a 2 dimensional one by using various integral representations of ${1\over |x|}$, for example:
$${1\over \|X-u\|  } \sim \int d\lambda  e^{-\lambda^2 \|X-u\|^2}.$$  Working from

$$ \mathbb{E}\int d\lambda d\mu (X-u_1)(X-u_2)  e^{-\lambda^2 \|X-u_1\|^2 -\mu^2\|X-u_2\|^2}$$

The d-dimensional $dX$ integral now becomes doable, at the expense of the two new variables. I tried pushing a bit, but it becomes rather tedious. The good thing about it is it may allow you to better identify the $u_1^2,u_2^2,u_1\cdot u_2$ dependencies.

Comment: This is insightful... Thanks!